# Ruby Inheritance Puzzle: How to Properly Call self.class.new in Parent Method

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I have a library that I would use in an app by using a class that wraps the library object in a new class by inheriting from it and adding a few instance variables.  I can change the library code if need be.  Here is the problem:

```
class A
  def process_it
    # Make a new instance
    aa = self.class.new
    do_something_to(aa)
  end

  def do_something_to(item)
    item
  end
end

class B < A
  def initialize(extra = "Default extra")
    @extra = extra
    super()
  end

  def extra
    @extra
  end
end

# I want B to inherit A's methods, like #process_it but:
b = B.new("Non-default extra")
puts b.process_it.extra => Default extra
```

The output should have been "Non-default extra" and the problem is that, in the parent class I call self.class.new but can pass no parameter to it to set @extra.  In the call, self.class is B, the inherited class, but when I write the parent class library, A, I cannot predict what, if any parameters, should be passed to self.class.new.  Indeed, I might have class C < A with different parameters for initialize.

Is there a proper way to write the code in library A to instantiate a new instance of the self class that takes possible parameters into account?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. Why would `b` create a temp instance of `B` instead of doing_something_to itself.

Comment: In the call to `self.class.new` from class A, you would need to pass the correct and expected `extra` value.

If every subclass has an `extra` method, your class A `process_it` method could look something like this:

```
class A
  def process_it
    aa = self.class.new(self.extra)
    do_something_to(aa)
  end
  # ... omitted remaining code
end

Still, maybe I did not grasp your use case completely, but it seems odd to instantiate a class when instantiating the same class (in this case, instantiating a B instance when instantiating the B class).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, because #do_something is very long and involved and there are over a dozen #do_somethings, which was the whole point of the library.  I want B to act like an A but with a little something extra.

Comment: @DanielDoherty: I am not convinced by this explanation, but if you insist, you can move the object creation into a factory method: `aa = create_new_instance`, where `B` would override this method to pass `extra`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, actually, that's a pretty good idea too.  It would be a faster than the dup idea I accepted below, so thanks for giving this some thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will [`#dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) work for you? Instead of `aa = self.class.new`, change it to `aa = self.dup`

Comment: Not if `do_something_to` mutates `@extra`. Per the docs: "Produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are copied, but **not the objects they reference**.".

Comment: Yes, @Iuri G., I think that's the only way to go.  What I did was to create a new method in A called empty_dup that would preserve the inherited instance variables but hand me an empty instance of class A, just like self.class.new.  So I just call something like `result = empty_dup` in my class A code whenever I want a fresh empty object to work with, but passing on any inherited instance variables.  Thanks for taking a look at this.